# How can I record work history or log including command and output on terminal with fish?

Tags: shell, terminal, config, fish

I'm trying to edit `/.config/fish/config.fish` and add script like this `env now= date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S ;set path /Users/t/logs/script_{$now}.txt ;script {$path}`. But it does not work.

**How should I edit `config.fish` file in order to record terminal log including output ?**

Comment: you want `set now (date ...)`. Assuming you fix your command substitution syntax, when you run `env var=(some value)`, the variable is only set for the duration of the env command.

Comment: You should always include the version of all relevant software when asking a question. In this case you need to tell us which version of fish you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your attempt to incorporate a timestamp in the file name is wrong. It should be `now=(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`. Too, prefixing it with the `env` command means it won't be visible to the subsequent statements because the `env` causes the var to only be visible to whatever command is part of the `env` command. What you wrote is the equivalent of

```
env now=something
path=...
script $path
```

That first `env` will simply add `now` to the env vars then display the list of env vars.

Second, you should ensure this is only done for interactive shells:

```
if status is-interactive
    now=(...)
    set path /Users/...$now.txt
    script $path
end
```

Third, you need to avoid infinite recursion. If you don't then the shell started by the `script` command will start another `script`'ed session. There are many ways to do this but the simplest is an env var:

```
if test -z "$SCRIPTED"
    set -gx SCRIPTED nested
    now=(...)
    path=/Users/...$now.txt
    script $path
end
```

Fourth, you may want to do `exec script $path` once you're sure this is working reliably. Otherwise when you exit the captured session you're returned to a non-capturing shell and you may not notice the transition. Alternatively, add something like `echo WARNING: your session is no longer being captured` after the `script` command to help make it really obvious.